# Can I provide explicit SPN for kerberos authentication in python?

Tags: python, kerberos

Python kerberos module seems to resolve the spn to the hostname. I want to provide an explicit SPN sch as 'SERVICE/DOMAIN'. However, when I enabled the KRB5_TRACE, it showed that it was trying to get the tickets for the principal 'SERVICE/\DOMAIN/LOCAL_MACHINE_NAME@DOMAIN.COM'.

Is there a way to tell python kerberos module to explicitly get the tickets against the provided SPN ?

Answer (score 0):

Python obviously uses C GSS-API in the backend. You have to tweak that. MIT Kerberos or Heimdal.